# I was using curl to post instead of a regular browser but I got usernames and passwords! how?

Tags: curl, post

I registered in a forum. and was using it as a regular user. one day my password was stolen, and at that moment I did not understand how it was done.

Suddenly when I was trying to POST using `curl -b "cookies" --data "data"` just to learn how to use curl I found out that when I sent the POST that the user names, passwords, emails and even IPs were in the output of the terminal, the information was of that particular user who I was posting on his page, and I was astonished!

**I didn't understand what is happening! Why did that happen? And is that usual?**

Comment: It depends on the authentication method, if it is simple: `http://login:password@your-url` if the web uses a login form, It 'll be a little bit different.

Comment: They use a login form. but when I used curl I didn't login with my username and password I just used the cookies that were in my browser. @DavidPérezCabrera

Comment: @user37421 when you used `curl`, cookies are not taken from your browser, but from file stored on the server...

Comment: But when I used the cookies it did work and the comment was posted @Legionar

Comment: I got the cookies for that specific site and put it in front of curl -b it looked like this curl -b "cookies" --data "the post content" @Legionar

Comment: @user37421 so maybe they used cookies to let users stay online without need to login again... so then there is no problem.

Comment: What do you mean? I got the passwords of the other users and my account was stolen some time ago. @Legionar

Answer (score 1):

This could be symptom of a [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Suppose we have a `users` table (including the `username`, `password`, `email`, and `last_ip` fields among others) and a `comments` table (including the `content` field among others).

When a user posts a comment they actually send a HTTP request that may look like this:

```
POST /blog/comment HTTP/1.1
(some headers here)
post_id=42&comment=Thanks
```

The server will then insert this comment into the database, but the inclusion of the parameters may be insecure:

```
// $comment is straight from the HTTP request
mysqli('INSERT INTO comments (content) VALUES (' . $comment . ');');
```

It is then possible to send a carefully crafted comment that result in the following SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO comments (content) VALUES (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(username, ',', password, ',', email, ',', last_ip) separator ';') FROM users)
```

This would basically dump the content of the `users` table as a blog comment that would then be happily displayed in the forum.

Of course this would be too obvious so a slightly sneakier variant would be to surround this dump with `<!--` and `-->` to turn it into an HTML comment that the web browser will hide but `curl` won't.

Comment: but I didn't do that I just used curl -b "cookies=text" --data "content=text&postid=number"

Comment: YOU didn't, but you got the post page back, and curl displayed it in raw form.

Comment: so, the page source should display the passwords?

Comment: If someone carried out the attack described above and hid the result as a comment, yes they would be hidden by the browser but visible in the page source.

Comment: I changed my question so that it is more clear. I hope you post your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269771 I said firebug but in fact I used curl.