# Inspecting POST response shows emails and passwords of other users

Tags: network-programming, http-post

In some forum that I was viewed the JSON response of a POST request using Firebug.

Say, a user with the email X@Y.com and password Zabc123 posted something on his own page on this forum. And I wanted to post a **comment** on his post.
But before I posted the comment I opened Firebug's *Net* panel:

After I had posted the comment the response that I saw in Firebug was like this:

> postid 1432
>
> OTHER THINGS ...
>
> email X@Y.com
>
> password Zabc123
>
> ip 111.111.111.111
>
> lastlogin 1-1-2016
>
> lastpasschange 2-2-2015
>
> and so on ..

This info **is not my own**, it is the info of the person that I was posting a comment on.

Is this a symptom of a hack or an incorrectly programmed script in that forum?

Answer (score 1):

If you see the account data of another user within the response info, then that's probably a bug in the server-side script you called in your POST request, especially if that happens equally in different browsers.
The programmers of the website could also have output it as debug info and forgot to remove the code when pushing it to the live server.

It could also be that the server got hacked and the script changed that way that it returns the user names and passwords in plain text.

Comment: Can a hacker change the server-side script?

Comment: Of course they can if they gain access to the server get root (i.e. admin) privileges, they can do whatever they want. I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: In any case, it should be fixed as soon as possible. So, if you're not the owner of that website, you should report this to the administration of it immediately.

Comment: I reported this issue to the administrator and it has been solved. But I'm wondering whether the hacker can do this again or not.

Comment: If it was a hacker attack, it's the administrators job to find out how the attacker could modify the script, but that's not a trivial task. Though that topic is out of the scope of Stack Overflow.